# Word files to PDF w/o losing image quality

Tags: microsoft-word, images, pdfcreator

I will admit I am a total noob when it comes to this. I have a Word 2010 file that has images and when I do either Save As PDF or print using a PDFCreator, I always get images with jagged diagonal lines and generally of worse quality. I tried it with JPEG as well as PNG, I tried it with Word 2010 and OpenOffice. No luck.

I even turned image compression off in Word 2010...still compressed it.

What am I doing wrong? Surely, there is a way to keep some quality when it comes to images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free PDF printers produce ugly images?](http://superuser.com/questions/20821/free-pdf-printers-produce-ugly-images)

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem with PDFCreator, but Try **doPDF**, it works.

http://www.dopdf.com/

Comment: thanks, but I get an error opening document, access denied.

Comment: I use doPDF for 2 years now, also install it for my clients without any problem, sorry if it doesn't help.